# Reusing jQuery UI Themeroller Overlay

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Trying to conserve css-loading bandwidth. I'm trying to reuse the overlay from jQuery UI for just a small section of the page - say, within a certain div. Can't seem to get the overlay to cover anything but a (semitransparent) blackout of the entire page. Integration CSS help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your question was answered here [How can I just open an Overlay (like dialog without title bar) in jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679632/how-can-i-just-open-an-overlay-like-dialog-without-title-bar-in-jquery-ui)