# How can I just open an Overlay (like dialog without title bar) in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui

How can I just open something similar to what I see in the theme roller site?

[image]

Alternatively, can I open a jQuery Dialog without the title bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the option DialogClass:
`$('.selector').dialog({ dialogClass: 'notitle' });`
and in the CSS specify your class by removing the title ecc
`.notitle .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none}`